# SQL: Union of two tables multiple CTEs

Tags: sql, union, common-table-expression

My goal is to do a union two tables in SQL, where each of the tables is complex and has to define a common table expression of its own, using `with table as alias` syntax.

So we have the first table with the following syntax:

```
with table1 as (
select/from/where statement),

table2 as (
select/from where statement),

select table1 join table2 on [...]
```

And the second table, with an analogous syntax:

```
with table3 as (
select/from/where statement),

table4 as (
select/from where statement),

select table3 join table4 on [...]
```

**My problem is: simply putting `union` between these two tables does not cut it**. The compiler sees the `union` between the two tables above as incorrect expression.

(My alternative approach, to define the whole first table as table5 and the whole second table as table6 to union them afterwards failed, since you cannot stack several "with as" statements into each other, seemingly.)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: The solution of Tab Alleman resolved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put all your CTEs before the first SELECT, but then you can UNION them as though they were tables:

```
WITH Table1 AS (..)
, Table2 AS (..)
, Table3 AS (..)
, Table4 AS (..)
SELECT Table1 JOIN Table2..
UNION 
SELECT Table3 JOIN Table4..
```